# react native restart application

Tags: react-native, expo, barcode-scanner

I created a barcode scanner App using expo-barcode-scanner.
I have some problems.

The purpose of the scanner is to get the barcode number and send it to barcode.monster and get product details. It works, but I have two main problems which I dont know what should I look for and how to resolve.

1. After the scanner get a barcode, I want to send to a confirmation screen, where the User should add the product into a category.

```
const handleBarCodeScanned = ({ type, data }) => {
       reqForProduct(data);
       setScanned(true);
       setText(data);
       navigation.navigate('Confirmation');
   };
```

The function above is executed when the barcode camera find a number.

```
  const reqForProduct = async barcode => {
        try {
            const Product = await axios.get(`https://barcode.monster/api/${barcode}`);
            console.log(Product.data);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
```

The function above is responsible to get the product data.

THE NAVIGATION WORKS, BUT IF I PRESS THE BACK BUTTON AFTER THE FUNCTION SEND ME TO THE CONFIRMATION SCREEN, I CANNOT RESCAN OTHER BARCODE UNLESS I PRESS R (RELOAD) IN THE CONSOLE... THIS IS MY FIRST PROBLEM. Moreover, after coming back to the screen, the console is stucked with the last product fetched from the api.

2. The second problem is is to transfer the data fetched to the confirmation screen. I tried with the `navigation` prop like `navigation.navigate('Confirmation', {fetchedDataObj}` but is not working....

   ```
   <Stack.Screen
        name='Confirmation' 
        component={AddToContainerScreen} />
   ```

THE FULL PAGE CODE BELLOW ----------------------------------------------------

```
import {View, Text, Button, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import { BarCodeScanner } from 'expo-barcode-scanner';
import axios from 'axios';



const Scanner = ({navigation}) => {

    const [permission, setPermission]   = useState(null);
    const [scanned, setScanned]         = useState(false);
    const [text, setText]               = useState('');

    const permissionCamera = () => {
        ( async () => {
            const {status} = await BarCodeScanner.requestPermissionsAsync();
            setPermission(status == 'granted');
        })()
    }

    const reqForProduct = async barcode => {
        try {
            const Product = await axios.get(`https://barcode.monster/api/${barcode}`);
            console.log(Product.data);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }

    // Execute permission
    useEffect(() => {
        permissionCamera();
    }, []);

    const handleBarCodeScanned = ({ type, data }) => {
        reqForProduct(data);
        setScanned(true);
        setText(data);
        navigation.navigate('Confirmation');
    };

    if (!permission) {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>Requesting camera permission</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }


    return (
        <View style={styles.wrapper}>
          <BarCodeScanner 
            style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill}
            onBarCodeScanned={scanned ? undefined : handleBarCodeScanned}
          />
      </View>
    )
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    wrapper: {
        flex: 1
    }
})

export default Scanner;
```

Can someone please help me?
BTW THE PRODUCT DATA FROM tHE API COMES SLOWeR THAN the APP MOVES TO THE CONFIRMATION SCREEN...

Answer (score 0):

Problem 1: I think you need to reinitialize it on a focus even listener or something.

```
useEffect(() => {
    permissionCamera();
}, []);
```

since **useEffect()** is basically a **componentOnMount** and it only fires the first time you load the page. When you navigate back this is not gonna fire. Please check if this is the case. You can do a simple log to confirm this.

For the 2nd problem, I can't help you much since there is only very little data. If you really need help, you could dm me on skype. I'll be glad to help you out.